# Bluetooth programming with Qt

Tags: c++, qt, bluetooth

I couldn't find many libraries for bluetooth programming using qt for mac osx.I would mostly be using RFCOMM protocal coz I just need to send serial data from arduino to laptop wirelessly.What are the Qt bluetooth libraries available so that I can send serial data wirelessly.I'm working on Mac Osx Mountain Lion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Admittedly: given that Qt is in a sense "a platform" in its own right, it's hard to define precisely what the scope of its services are vs. what an OS does.

For instance: you can use it to do things like [count the number of screens on the system](http://doc.qt.digia.com/qt/qdesktopwidget.html#screenCount-prop), and that might seem kind of outside-the-box or "OS-like".

But these things are narrowly chosen.  They only creep in when they're applicable to all the platforms Qt runs on...as well as being a common case for Qt programs in many different domains.  It doesn't apply to something like (let's say) getting a list of names of all the WiFi networks and their signal strengths.

So what you're really asking about is what external library to link into a Qt C++ program to do Bluetooth serial programming on OS/X.  I don't know, but as it's a Mac the native programming interface an Objective-C framework:

[Bluetooth on Mac OS/X Framework](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/devicedrivers/Conceptual/Bluetooth/BT_Bluetooth_On_MOSX/BT_Bluetooth_On_MOSX.html)

So if you are writing a Mac-only program, the path of least resistance might be to load up XCode and learn enough Objective-C in XCode to get it going.

After that if you really want to use C++ and Qt, you could try to figure out the right linkage voodoo to make it work.  Or keep the communication program as a small standalone process still written in Objective-C, and talk to it some other way (like through standard input and output).

If you go down the road of linking direct to C++, there's some mention of C++ headers:

```
#include <IOBluetooth/IOBluetoothUserLib.h> 
#include <IOBluetooth/IOBluetoothUtilities.h>
```

So search the web on that and you might find more.